# Не работает форма

Tags: php, form

Доброго времени суток.
Прошу помощи у гуру. Подскажите, где здесь ошибка

```css
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}
    if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone'];}
    if (isset($_POST['formData'])) {$formData = $_POST['formData'];}


    $to = "2137@yandex.ru"; 
    $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset = utf-8";
    $subject = "$formData";
    $message = "$mes\n\nИмя пославшего: $name \n\nТелефон: $phone";
    $send = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if ($send == 'true')
    {
    echo "<center>Спасибо! Мы перезвоним Вам в самое ближайшее время</center>";
    }
    else 
    {
    echo "<center><b>Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено!</b></center>";
    }
} else {
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "Попробуйте еще раз";
}
?>
```

```html
<form method="post" action="mail.php" style="position: relative;top: 16px;">

        <input type="text" class="put name borderl" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" required title="Введите имя">
        <input type="text" class="phone borderl" pattern="^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$" name="phone" placeholder="Номер телефона" required title="Введите номер телефона в формате +7 (999) 999-99-99">
        <input type="submit" class="btn borderl borderl2" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ">
        <input type="hidden" name="formData" value="Заказать звонок">
    </form>
```

```
Mail.php:
```

Comment: А какую ошибку выбивает при отправке?  С сервера отправляете, или с домашней тачки?

Comment: Ошибок нет. После нажатия кнопки ничего не происходит.

Comment: Добро пожаловать в волшебный мир программирования: http://phpfaq.ru/debug

Answer (score -2):

```
<?
if(isset($_POST)){
    $headers = "From: <admin@".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].">\r\n";
    $headers = $headers."Return-path: <no-replay@".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].">\r\n";
    $headers = $headers."Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r";
$msg = '';
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
$msg.='<b>'.$key.'</b>: '.$value.'<BR>';
}
mail ("admin@".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], "Запрос с сайта: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $msg, $headers);
}
?>
```

Comment: Так же убедитесь что порт 25 открыт

Comment: Если ты ищешь место, где можешь писать код любому желающему, то Stack Overflow неподходящий для этого сайт.

Comment: @Артур не вижу ответа на вопрос автора «где здесь ошибка»

Comment: Возможно в отсутствие From.
+ ошибка необязательно заключается в коде, я сказал проверить 25-й порт , в добавок почтовики могут отказаться принять почту иза неправильной настройки spf/dkim/dmarc записи. Остыньте и успокоите свои таланты . Смысл скрипта проверить работу почты на уровне сервера.